# Lower_bound not working on the last element of a vector with 3 elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, lower-bound

```
vector<int> vec = {2,4,3};
vector<int>::iterator it;
it=lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),3);
cout<<*it;
```

This returns an output of 4 not 3 but

```
vector<int> vec = {2,3,4};
vector<int>::iterator it;
it=lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),3);
cout<<*it;
```

But this returns the correct output of 3. Please help me understand why it is failing in the corner case.

Comment: Why did you expect `3` in the first case? The docs say it [returns an iterator ... to the first element ... that is not less than ...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and its documentation of `std::lower_bound`:

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
>   last) that is not less than **(i.e. greater or equal to)** value, or last
>   if no such element is found.

So, `std::lower_bound` returns the **first element** that is **greater or equal to the** value (3 here).

For {2, 4, 3}, the first element greater or equal to 3 is 4, but for {2, 3, 4,} it is 3.

**P.S.** According to the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) again:

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the
>   expression **element < value or comp(element, value)**, i.e., all elements
>   for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which
>   the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

Both of your vectors are partitioned correctly with the condition (element < value)

Answer (score 0):

In short, the vector `{2,4,3}` doesn't meet the requirements of `lower_bound`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound says:

> The range [first, last) must be partitioned with respect to the
>   expression element < value or comp(element, value), i.e., all elements
>   for which the expression is true must precede all elements for which
>   the expression is false. A fully-sorted range meets this criterion.

If your vector is not sorted then use `std::find`.

Comment: No, [turns out](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) it being partitioned with respect to `x < 3` is good enough.